# How to pass a character to printf that was input by user in C?

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I am just starting with C and trying to grasp the whole idea of pointers and I just came across the following issue.

I am trying to print out a character that was input by the user passing it to a separate function:

```
#define MAX_OPTION_INPUT 1
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0


// print a menu
void getCharacter() {   
    char getNum[MAX_OPTION_INPUT+2];
    int finished = FALSE;

    // get character from user
    do {
        fgets(getNum, MAX_OPTION_INPUT+2, stdin);
        if (getNum[strlen(getNum) - 1] != '\n') {
            printf("Input one digit number please.\n");
            readRestOfLine();
      }
      else {
         getNum[strlen(getNum) - 1] = '\0';
         finished = TRUE;
      }
   } while (!finished);

    processChar(getNum);
}


// process menu
void processChar(char num) {
    printf("TADA: %c", num);
}
```

When I compile this code I get a warning: *passing argument 1 of 'processChar' makes integer from pointer without a cast*

And when I run it it prints out some weird character instead of the one that I supposed to pass.

Could you please explain to me where I am missing the point here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You never actually call `processChar` in that code.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the whole thing was actually a part of a bigger code, I just narrowed it down to those two functions. *Edited

Comment: You accepted an answer that told you to change the signature of the function.  You don't need to; you simply need to pass the correct type.  When you pass in `getNum` the array degrades into a pointer to `char`, so you're passing in a pointer to a function that expects a `char`. Instead, simply pass in `getNum[0]` (or whichever element is appropriate.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the function to accept a `char *`:

```
void processChar(const char *num)
{
    printf("TADA: %s", num); /* %s instead of %c */
}
```

> Could you please explain to me where I am missing the point here?

You're passing and using `num` as if it's a character when it's actually a character array.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. But why do you need to put 'const' in there?

Comment: you don't /need/ to. however it is good style to use const to tell the compiler you aren't going to update something. Not only does it allow the compiler more flexibility in optimisation, it means you guarantee not to alter what is passed into you, and the compiler can check you do just that.

Comment: @KonstantinLevin, What if another function wants to pass in a `const char *` or `const char[]` since your function doesn't change it? This is what happens: http://ideone.com/HRL36. This is something that actually comes up often in C++ because there's a `string` "type" that you can convert to `const char *`, but if you try to call a function that takes `char *` when it really could have taken `const char *`, you have to do extra work to convert the result of the string to `const char *` conversion to non-const.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! By the way, was it printing out a weird character before I changed it to a pointer because it was just printing out the address from the stack instead of the actual value?

Comment: @KonstantinLevin That's the most likely explanation.